# Multi-User Login Issues in Visual Basic 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have the following code, which is meant to show a different page based on the login credentials. Fow example, logging in as admin should show the AdminPanel and logging in as anyone else should show UserPanel. The issues is, no matter who you login as, it shows UserPanel.

```
    Try
        Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim adaptor As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dataset As New DataSet
        connection.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FSMembers;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
        command.CommandText = "select * from [users] where username='" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and password ='" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "' and Position='admin or user' " '
        connection.Open()
        command.Connection = connection
        adaptor.SelectCommand = command
        adaptor.Fill(dataset, "0")
        Dim count = dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        If count < 1 Then
            UserPanel.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            AdminPanel.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("You have inserted invalid Login details." & vbNewLine & "Please try again!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login Failed | FS Members")
            UsernameTextBox.Clear()
            PasswordTextBox.Clear()
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction here.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Most probably your query is not doing what you think it is doing. That last part `and Position='admin or user' " '` would raise some eyebrows.

Comment: haha I know the code is not doing what I hope it is doing or think it is doing, hense my post. :) Position is a Database Colum.

Comment: So why don't you just run your query directly in Management Studio or even from within VS and see if you get the results that you expect? We don't know your database strucuture or how you're storing user types so we can never be sure.

Comment: I did.... That's why I am posting here. It just logs in. No errors or anything. Just not logging into the correct place based on the user I am logging in with.

Comment: Tell me just one thing. What do you store in `Position` column? My guess is that it would either be 'admin' or 'user' but not 'admin or user', or is it?

Comment: It would be 'admin' or 'user'. For example, the username "admin" would have the Position of 'admin' and therefore have access to AdminPanel

Comment: And when you debug your code? What is coming out of the database query? By debugging, you'll be able to pinpoint your exact problem. Then it will be easier to address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
Try
   Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
   Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
   command.CommandText = "SELECT Position from [users] WHERE username='" & UsernameTextBox.Text & "' and password ='" & PasswordTextBox.Text & "'"
   connection.Open()
   command.Connection = connection
   Dim Res = command.ExecuteScalar()

   If Res IsNot Nothing Then 
      If Res.ToString().ToLower() <> "admin" Then
        UserPanel.Show()
        Me.Hide()
      Else
        AdminPanel.Show()
        Me.Hide()
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox("You have inserted invalid Login details." & vbNewLine & "Please try again!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Login Failed | FS Members")
        UsernameTextBox.Clear()
        PasswordTextBox.Clear()
   End If
Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I'm writing this in SO editor, so there may be minor typos. Most importantly what I want you to understand is that this way of constructing queries would expose your application to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should really consider creating a stored procedure for it, or use some application-level way of sending parameters to your query rather than concatenating textbox values into strings.

Comment: Okay mate, that worked, but the opposite way around. The admin is logging into UserPanel and the user is logging into AdminPanel.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But that's still doing the same as before (opposite access)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `If Res.ToString().ToLower() <> "admin" Then` line and tell me what value do u get in `Res`.

Comment: > FSMembers.exe!FSMembers.FormLogin.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 37 Basic
  String "0" String
That's all I get from it.

Comment: Just in case you haven't done this before, take (keyboard) cursor to that line (`If Res.ToString().ToLower() <> "admin" Then`) and press `F9`. This will turn the line background to brown color indicating that a breakpoint has been set at that line. Now run your code. The code will stop at that line and you'll be take to VS. Take your mouse to the `Res` variable and a tooltip will show you the current value of Res. What do you see?

Comment: This means your `Position` column doesn't store 'admin' or 'user', but instead saves '0' or '1', right? Can you open the table and confirm that? If this is the case, simply replace "admin" with "1" in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted
I changed the following:

```
 If Res IsNot Nothing Then 
  If Res.ToString().ToLower() <> "admin" Then
    UserPanel.Show()
    Me.Hide()
  Else
    AdminPanel.Show()
    Me.Hide()
  End If
```

To:

```
                If Res IsNot Nothing Then
            If Res.ToString().ToLower() <> "admin" Then
                AdminPanel.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            Else
                UserPanel.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
```

It works now.
Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: There is something wrong in your system. The above code shouldn't work. You're asking it to show admin panel if user type is NOT admin. Wish you figure this out soon.

Comment: You are correct. After that worked, I figured something was wrong and found that the Database Tables were back to front for some odd reason. All sorted now using your code. Thanks again so much. My Internet was down last night so couldn't reply then and I am unable to Vote for answers. But sincerely thank you.